# Perl stash output

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a code snippet from the Advanced Perl Programming book for dumping the stash. This is without any additional packages from CPAN.

The package containing the stash related instructions is as follows:

```
package DUMPVAR;

sub dumpvar {
    my ($packageName) = @_;

    local (*alias);
    *stash = *{"${packageName}::"};

    $, = " ";

    while (($varName, $globValue) = each %stash) {

        print "\n $varName ===========================================\n";
        *alias = $globValue;

        if (defined ($alias)) {
            print "\t \$$varName $alias \n";
        }
        if (@alias) {
            print "\t \@$varName @alias \n";
        }
        if (keys %alias) {
            print "\t \%$varName " , %alias, " \n";
        }
    };
};
1;
```

The calling code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DUMPVAR;

package MyData;

my $x = 10;
my @y = (1,2,3);
my %z = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
my $z = 300;

DUMPVAR::dumpvar('MyData');
```

I get no output what so ever. what is the problem?

Comment: `MyData` contains no symbols. You created lexical variables which have nothing to do with packages. You'll get what you want if you remove the `my`.

Comment: Use `local $, = " ";` instead of `$, = " ";`

Comment: Tip: You could use `DUMPVAR::dumpvar(__PACKAGE__);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see anything because you've only defined lexical variables. Those aren't tracked in the package system. Get rid of `my` (and `strict` because you haven't declared things, and `warnings` because you only use things once):

```
package MyData;

$x = 10;
@y = (1,2,3);
%z = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
$z = 300;

Dumpvar::dumpvar('MyData');
```

The output is:

```
 y ===========================================
     @y 1 2 3

 x ===========================================
     $x 10

 z ===========================================
     $z 300
     %z  3 4 5 6 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Lexical Variables defined with my are not stored in the package.

You have to either declare them with "our" (instead of my), or don't declare them at all and add

```
use vars qw($x @y %z $z);
```

to add them to the package.